# Seekbar Listener

Tags: java, android, seekbar

Thank you guys for helping me with the seekbar problem... i believe most of the problems were fixed, but there are 2 new errors... I'm so sorry.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private RadioGroup rgsexo;
EditText editPeso;
EditText editAltura;
TextView imcView;
SeekBar alterarAltura;
SeekBar alterarPeso;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    alterarAltura.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(alteraralturaListener);
    editPeso = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPeso);
    editAltura = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAltura);
    imcView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imcView);
    alterarAltura = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.alterarAltura);
    alterarPeso = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.alterarPeso);
    alterarAltura.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(alteraralturaListener);

}

private OnSeekBarChangeListener alteraralturaListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
    boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Calcula o novo valor do TIP
        editAltura=(alterarAltura.getProgress()) * .01;
        // mostra na caixa o valor novo
        alterarAltura.setText(String.format("%.02f", editAltura).replace(',', '.'));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
};
```

The erros are

"editAltura=(alterarAltura.getProgress()) * .01;"
Type missmatch, cannot convert edittext to double

"alterarAltura.setText(String.format("%.02f", editAltura).replace(',', '.'));"
The method of setText(String) is undefined for the type SeekBar

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, rearrange your activity code as below then say the the problem you are facing or not.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private RadioGroup rgsexo;
    EditText editPeso;
    EditText editAltura;
    TextView imcView;
    SeekBar alterarAltura;
    SeekBar alterarPeso;
    alterarAltura.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(alteraralturaListener);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        editPeso = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPeso);
        editAltura = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAltura);
        imcView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imcView);
        alterarAltura = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.alterarAltura);
        alterarPeso = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.alterarPeso);
        alterarAltura.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(alteraralturaListener);

    }

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener alteraralturaListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Calcula o novo valor do TIP
            editAltura=(alterarAltura.getProgress()) * .01;
            // mostra na caixa o valor novo
            alterarAltura.setText(String.format("%.02f", editAltura).replace(',', '.'));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`alterarAltura.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(alteraralturaListener);` needs to be inside a method (like `onCreate(...)`).

Answer (score 1):

you have set the wrong variables: alterarAltura is a SeekBar. Copy this in onProgressChanged:

```
double myDouble = (alterarAltura.getProgress()) * .01d;
// mostra na caixa o valor novo
editAltura.setText(String.format("%.02f", myDouble).replace(',', '.'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it says that cannot invoke getprogress() on the primitive type double

Comment: Hi! My ADV shuts down unexpectadly after trying to run this code. No erros are detected!
Could you check it out if i put the entire code here?